# How to use and insert an SVG file inside a div

Tags: html, image, svg

I have been provided an .SVG file and I need to use it inside a div. I have tried using:

```
<div class="resultsCapacity">  
      <img class="Good" src="Image.svg" alt="test Passed">
</div>
```

All that shows is `test Passed`. My question is what other options should I use/try. Any suggestions that would help guide me in the right direction would also help.

Comment: You are seeing test passed because image is not found, is your image is in same folder as your html?

Comment: Please note - svg file can be used as any image file in img tag - https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: @kewlashu the file is in the same ... directory?

Comment: Then I am not sure what's the issue here because all sems ok...you should check file name and path